# What is the location of OSB Message Reports on the server

Tags: weblogic11g, osb

We want to periodically archive the log files as well as the report files on the production server.
I could locate the log file but not the files which contains reports.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could someone please let me know the reason for down voting so that I can prevent future mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reports are stored in your Oracle Database.

```
Schema:[DOMAIN_NAME]_SOAINFRA
Tables:WLI_QS_REPORT_ATTRIBUTE and WLI_QS_REPORT_DATA
```

Comment: This is useful. However on my local environment my OSB is not connected with Oracle (or any other DB). Still I'm able to see old reports after server restarts.

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but isn't a DB required to install OSB? Or atleast needed for the reporting? I found: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e15017/before.htm#BABCJHDJ

Comment: Useful. Since Reports will be saved in the DB, file path is just a curiosity  <Middleware>\<wlserver>\common\derby\demo\databases\osbexamples\seg0\c4d0.dat

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answer, but it may be useful to add.
On a local machine if you have integrated Weblogic, you can get access to local DB (Derby) in this way:
http://shiladityasoaworld.blogspot.com/2016/04/12c-soainfra-database-connection-in.html